# SharePoint list view created from multiple lists on the same site

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I want to create a SharePoint list/ view comprimised of multiple columns from different lists on the same site.

Do I have to create a separate list for this or can I simply create a view? The reason why I am doing this is to be able to use reporting webparts that require a **single** list as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Data view webpart available in SPD to join multiple list data in a single view or you create a separate list